# Difference among "an", "in", "von", "aus"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, preposition

I am puzzled about these preposition in Deutsch.
What's the main difference among them?

I have a example. I give my understanding after the Deutsch. Can I understanding in this way?

> Das Es → The it?
>   An Es → on/at/by it?
>   In Es → in it?
>   Vom Ich → from I?
>   Aus Mir → from me?
>   Ich ins Es → I in it?

**Added explanation**: I know this is a bad example. But it is from a German book. That's why I feel so confused. This kind of usage is not common.
If my understanding is wrong, please tell me how to understand them in a right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those examples make little to no sense. This is mostly because you haven't declined *es* properly. This is required because it makes a big difference whether a preposition is used with nominative, genitive, dative or accusative.

**In es** (accusative) for example means *into it*.

> Das Heft war fast voll. Ich schrieb weiter **in es** hinein.

*The notebook was nearly full. I continued to write **into it**.*

**In ihm** (dative) in contrary means *inside it*.

> **In ihm** (dem Heft) stand soviel Unsinn.

*Inside it (the notebook) was so much nonsense.*

Prepositions which take nominative or genitive are less common.

But most important, the meaning of prepositions in German (and in English, too) depend on the verbs they are connected with.

> Er klebte eine Notiz **an** die Tür.

*He stuck a note **to** the door.*

> Ich mag alles **an** ihr.

*I like everything **about** her.*

> **An** diesem Tag ging alles schief.

**At** that day all went wrong.

So there is no direct translation possible. You have to learn the multiple meanings of each single verb and which preposition is used for which meaning.

Comment: Those example are from a German book. I know that they look like a little strange. That's why I don't understand them.

Comment: @Echo Yang: please tell which book. It's horrible.

Answer (score 0):

"Das" and "es" are **substitutes** that mean "this" and "it," respectively. You would not use them together.

You don't decline **"es"** with prepositions. You would use e.g. an/in with dem, der, dem, or den (dative for location), depending on the gender/plurality of the underlying noun.

Von takes on a **dative object.** So you would say "von mir," not "von ich." You could also say "aus mir."